# How can I project date string or object instead of date number field in mongodb find query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a date field that is javascript number date and I want to get the string or object of date (like new Date(date)) in find query projection instead of date field itself that is number.

```js
//I want to get 
datetime:new Date(date)
//instead of 
db.myCollection.find({},{date:1})
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forEach or map function

```html
db.yourCollectionName.find({}).map(function(doc) {
    return {
        d:new Date(doc.datetime)
        };
});
```